# microsoft azure: Did i need to inform microsoft for third party testing on my azure app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to azure app. i have developed app and it should be going for testing by third party testing team. so should i need to inform Microsoft Azure team? if yes then please share details over here with email id

Comment: What do you infer by testing? Take a look at this: https://security-forms.azure.com/penetration-testing/terms and this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/mt346049.aspx

Comment: I mean the third party testing team will do testing my app. so its need to inform azure team for this?

Comment: Thanks I am getting the thing. here is the link to inform azure https://security-forms.azure.com/penetration-testing. thanks for your reply its really helpful